# Looking for a list of English words that are morphologically similar, semantically different?

Tags: syntax, english, terminology, orthography, dictionary

I need a list of **English** words that are **morphologically similar**, but when it comes to **meaning**, they should be **completely different**.

Comment: Can you look up the word *indifferent* in your favorite dictionary and confirm it conveys what you mean to convey? Similarly for *syntax* (probably you meant *morphologically*, but since you're talking about not even morphemes but individual letters, you want words that have similar *spellings*). I suggest all this so that you can clarify and pint down your question, as you're going to have a hard time answering it otherwise. Not every site will be willing to put as much effort into reading and inferring as SE is, and unfortunately SE can't answer list questions.

Comment: Just to elaborate on Dan Bron: do you mean that they share morphemes, share morphological patterns (e.g., prefix+stem), merely appear to share morphemes (e.g., corn, corner), or what?

Comment: The latter, Jeremy. @JeremyNeedle

Comment: If you organize by spellings instead of sounds, this  introduces uncontrolled variables, the result of which is that your findings can apply only to literate English speakers.

Answer (score 2):

In Appendix A and Appendix B of [Rastle, Davis, Marslen-Wilson, Tyler (2000)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01690960050119689), there are listings of the stimuli used. You want the '-M-S+O’ condition (i.e., not related morphological or semantically, but similar orthographically). There are 48, I think, so maybe that will be helpful. They sometimes differ by more than 2 characters.

Comment: That is helpful but since most of them come from same root (i.e. `hotel-motel, cleaner-cleanly, sadly-sadness`, etc), they have similar meanings. What I look for is finding words that are **morphologically similar**, but have **different (unlike) meanings** such as the example you shared above (`corn - corner`)

Comment: Yes, those are the '-M-S+O' items. You're looking at the '+M+S+O' items.